# Characteristic frequency

Tags: terminology, frequency, spectroscopy

Can you please give me shortest possible (bare basic definition) of the characteristic frequency of a spectrum? All that google gives me are books and articles where I don't understand a word.

Comment: I would think that the characteristic frequency of a given spectrum is simply something like the average or midpoint frequency of that frequency spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

Any *pronounced feature,* (namely spikes or peaks ) with *different strengths,* (namely relative amplitude of each feature compared to the background,) in a frequency spectrum is known as *characteristic frequency.*

Answer (score 1):

Characteristic frequency could also refer to resonant frequency of a system as it is exposed to a spectrum of input frequencies. For example, consider a damped spring-mass system.

If one measured the amplitude of oscillation of the mass versus frequency of some driving force, one would get a spectrum which would have a peak in the spectrum whose shape and peak location would depend on the amount of damping. That peak would be the characteristic frequency.

Another example would be measuring the air input impedence of a musical wind instrument as a function of pulse frequency (or the Fourier spectrum of white noise input into the instrument). The result will be a spectrum with peaks of resonant frequencies. Those would be the characteristic frequencies of the instrument.

Answer (score 0):

The term *characteristic frequency* or characteristic wavelength is a language representation of a particular spectrum-

If the spectrum has a feature that "identifies" it in a conglomerate of so many or can be used as a comparative tool /marker in the group  its called characteristic frequency of the spectrum of say material  A.

As an example i heard this term when i was looking at *X-ray spectrum* of certain target materials like Copper, Molybdenum ...etc.

They were particular lines called characteristic lines pertaining to particular element being used as a target and suppose someone has forgotten -

which target he has loaded -he can look for those intense spectral lines(frequency/wavelength) and will know the target.

In emission spectra each element has such characteristic frequency -say like Ne. Na, Hg.. so on -
When we see those lines which are very sharp  we say that this material must be present in the discharge tube ,may be in trace amount.

In sodium vapor lamp spectrum apart from *Characteristic sodium doublet*- intense lines of Neon/Hg will be observed as an impurity- characteristic frequency of Ne/Hg registering its presence.

In absorption spectra also characteristic wavelengths are present- they are very Dark as if most of the time the atom goes to  those exited states to give off those Dark absorption lines.